# Create an animation on wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am creating an animation on the main wordpress page. To do this I am doing as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   (function mover(i){
      
      $('#seta').animate({top: (i ? "-" : "+")+"100px"}, 1000, function(){
         mover(!i);
      });
      
   }())
   
});
```

```css
#seta{
   position: relative;
}
.container img {
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height:250px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
.container {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
img {
    vertical-align: top
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="seta" class="container">

<a href="http://xxxxxxxxx.xx/recrutamento/"><img src="http://xxxxxxxxxxx.xx/wp-content/uploads/small.png" width="320" height="205" /></a>
<h1>Procura Emprego! Clique aqui!</h1>
</div>
```

I've tested it and it works, but I can't get it to work on my site.

I show in the image how I am doing:
[image]

But I get this error on the page as shown in the image:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see there are some `<p>` tags in your code, and you can't paste the code directly inside the editor.

In the **visual composer** (click on backend editor) you can find a module for code, search for javascript and paste only the js code or for html and paste the code inside the `<script>` tag.

Comment: I'm searching the visual composer but I can't find module for javascript code, can you show me how to find it?

Comment: search for raw html or raw js: https://visualcomposer.com/help/content-elements-structure/custom-html-javascript/

Comment: or I've found that there is another way to do the same, see this video: 
https://visualcomposer.com/help/settings/custom-css/